# How to install apps on separate HDD in Linux (Fedora)

Tags: linux, fedora, filesystems, hard-disk, application

I migrated from Windows to Linux. 
I have a 96 GB SSD, where I have my Fedora installed,
and a 1 TB external HDD. 
On MS-Windows I had my OS installed on SSD
and every app I was installing to HDD. 
How can I achieve this in Linux?

I tried to mount my HDD to `/opt`,
and when I tried to install google-chrome it crashed.

```
Total                                           3.9 MB/s |  86 MB     00:22     
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                                        1/1 
  Running scriptlet: google-chrome-unstable-94.0.4606.12-1.x86_64           1/1 
  Installing       : google-chrome-unstable-94.0.4606.12-1.x86_64           1/1 
Error unpacking rpm package google-chrome-unstable-94.0.4606.12-1.x86_64
Errors occurred during transaction.
  Verifying        : google-chrome-unstable-94.0.4606.12-1.x86_64           1/1 
Completion plugin: Generating completion cache...
Failed: google-chrome-unstable-94.0.4606.12-1.x86_64

Failed:
  google-chrome-unstable-94.0.4606.12-1.x86_64                                  

Error: Transaction failed
```

Disk is mounted like

```
/opt   /dev/sda2 vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset
```

(output from `findmont -T /opt`)

Comment: What kind of app you are trying to install ?

Comment: @IbnFulan I tried to install google-chrome

Comment: Edit question to tell us — Did it crash when you installed it?, when you ran it? What was the error message? What file-system do you have for `/opt`. Show output of `findmont -T /opt`.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor it crashed when installing via `dnf install google-chrome`
Output of findmont -T /opt is `/opt   /dev/sda2 vfat   rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset
 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works after I changed filesystem of disk to xfs now my mounting points looks like 
 `UUID=f955e00b-4141-45e9-bacd-9e36012e19fb /opt   xfs defaults,nofail 0 2`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the file-system. `vfat` does not support the required attributes.

`vfat` is an old MS file-system. Unix uses advanced features of a file-system, that `vfat` and `NTFS` do not have.

Specifically, chrome uses the set-uid bit. There may be others.